# Como converter a primeira letra de cada palavra para maiúscula?

Tags: php

Gostaria de manipular a forma que a pessoa digita o nome ao se cadastrar, para ficar apenas com a primeira letra do nome em caixa alta. Os exemplos que encontrei não fazem exatamente o que preciso.

No meu caso, se a pessoa digitar:

- joão adão
- JOÃO ADÃO

Deve ser convertido para **João Adão**. O [`ucwords()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ucwords.php) do PHP perde os acentos ao salvar no banco de dados.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ucfirst.php olha ai amigo

Comment: E se for José da Silva?

Comment: @Bacco, desculpe, mas ri muito aqui.

Answer (score 16):

Essa [resposta do SO<sup>en</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12066075/1342547) sugere o uso da função [`mb_convert_case()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-case.php). O primeiro argumento é a string a ser convertida, o segundo o modo respectivamente todas maiúsculas, todas minúsculas e iniciais maiúsculas (`MB_CASE_UPPER`, `MB_CASE_LOWER`, e `MB_CASE_TITLE`)  e o último a codificação.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$str = "isso é um teste í ã ó ç";
echo mb_convert_case($str, MB_CASE_TITLE, 'UTF-8');
```

**[PHPFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ytfr-1bcx)**

Comment: Vale comentar que a função funciona bem ao bem pé da letra mesmo. Caso a string do nome contenha alguma conectivo que deva orbigatoriamente ser mantido descapitalizado (de, do, da, e, von, van e etc.) bem como partes que precisam obrigatoriamente ser mantidas capitalizadas (Fulanod e Tal III, por exemplo) será preciso trabalhar um pouquinho mais.

Answer (score 7):

```
$str = 'LOREM IPSUM';

echo mb_convert_case($str, MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8");
```

http://php.net/mb_convert_case

Answer (score -1):

Utilize essa função que criei

```
function maiuscula($string) {
        $string = mb_strtolower(trim(preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $string)));//transformo em minuscula toda a sentença
        $palavras = explode(" ", $string);//explodo a sentença em um array
        $t =  count($palavras);//conto a quantidade de elementos do array
        for ($i=0; $i <$t; $i++){ //entro em um for limitando pela quantidade de elementos do array
            $retorno[$i] = ucfirst($palavras[$i]);//altero a primeira letra de cada palavra para maiuscula
                if($retorno[$i] == "Dos" || $retorno[$i] == "De" || $retorno[$i] == "Do" || $retorno[$i] == "Da" || $retorno[$i] == "E" || $retorno[$i] == "Das"):
                    $retorno[$i] = mb_strtolower($retorno[$i]);//converto em minuscula o elemento do array que contenha preposição de nome próprio
                endif;  
        }
        return implode(" ", $retorno);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```php
namespace App\Helpers;

class NameFormat
{
    /**
     * function standadizeTheNames
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return
     */
    public static function standadizeTheNames(string $name)
    {
        $upperExcept = ['da', 'de', 'di', 'do', 'a', 'e', 'o', 'dos'];

        return static::ucWordsExcept($name, $upperExcept);
    }

    /**
     * function ucWordsExcept
     *
     * @param string $string
     * @param array $except
     * @return
     */
    public static function ucWordsExcept(string $string, array $except = [])
    {
        $string = static::clearString($string);

        foreach (explode(' ', $string) as $word) {
            $word = \strtolower($word);

            if (\in_array($word, \array_values($except))) {
                $finalString[] = $word;
                continue;
            }

            $finalString[] = \ucfirst($word);
        }

        return implode(' ', $finalString ?? []) ?: $string;
    }

    /**
     * function clearString
     *
     * @param string $string
     * @param array $remove
     * @param array $replace
     * @return string
     */
    public static function clearString(string $string, array $remove = [], array $replace = []): string
    {
        $string = trim($string);

        $defaultToRemove = ['\\', '.', ','];
        $string = \str_replace(($defaultToRemove + $remove), '', $string);

        $defaultToReplace = ['  ' => ' '];
        $toReplace = !\array_is_list($replace) ? \array_merge($replace, $defaultToReplace) : $defaultToReplace;
        return \str_replace(\array_keys($toReplace), \array_values($toReplace), $string);
    }
}
```

Uso:

```php
\App\Helpers\NameFormat\standadizeTheNames('tiago frança'); 
// Tiago França

\App\Helpers\NameFormat\standadizeTheNames('pedro de lara');
// Pedro de Lara

\App\Helpers\NameFormat\standadizeTheNames('PEDRO DA SILVA');
// Pedro da Silva
```

Answer (score -3):

No meu caso eu só usei

```
ucwords(mb_strtolower($srting))
```

```
$string = 'JOÃO PÁYÃÔ';

$newString = ucwords(mb_strtolower($string));

echo $newString;
```

A mb_strtolower($string,"utf-8" ), ou seja, ela por padrão já irá converter toda sua string em lowercase com o padrão o utf-8;

Comment: Essa função tem problema. Se algum nome se iniciar acentuado não vai dar o resultado correto: https://ideone.com/1vL4cN

Comment: Verdade, nesse caso só usei o exemplo da pergunta, nesse contexto a melhor opção mesmo seria mb_convert_case($string, MB_CASE_TITLE, 'UTF-8');

Answer (score -4):

Voce pode fazer usando Javascript... dessa forma:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">

function capitalize(campoFormulario) {
 
 var string = document.getElementById(campoFormulario).value;
 
 if(string.length > 0) {
 
  string = string.toLowerCase();
  string = string.split(' ');
  
        for (var i = 0, len = string.length; i < len; i++) {
   
   if(string[i].length > 2) {
    
    string[i] = string[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string[i].slice(1);
    
   };
   
        };
  
  document.getElementById(campoFormulario).value = string.join(' ');
  return true;
  
 }
 
}

</script>
```

No html, no campo Input identificado com o id, ficara assim:

```html
<input type="text" name="campo_nome" id="campo_id" onkeyup="capitalize(this.id);">
```

Uma unica observação: quando eu coloco no codigo javascritp "if(string[i].length > 2)" estou indicando que quero capitalizar apenas as palavras que tiverem mais do que 2 caracteres... se preferir muda esse valor, ou apaga esse if.

Comment: Mas a tag da pergunta é php.

Comment: ola Diego... acredito ser impossivel manipular o valor ao digitar em php... ja que isso só aconteceria ao enviar o formulario... ate mesmo em css seria possivel controlar a exibicao do conteudo input... porem, ao enviar o formulario, o texto iria com os caracteres da forma como foram digitados